# How to fix a JFrame to a specific position?

Tags: java, user-interface, jframe

How can I set my JFrame to a specific psotion on the screen? I've already managed to fix its size. I want it to be at a standard location on the screen and not be moved by the user.

Comment: Why do you want to disable moving the window? It doesn't seem very user freindly

Comment: @Can'tTell There may be quite a few uses, a custom splash screen for once (I know Java has it's own ones for program start, but still)

Comment: I think I'm more curious to know how I would do it rather than applying it to a specific application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fixate it as follows:

```
frame.setResizable(false);
frame.setUndecorated(true);
```

Or better: by adding a Component listener:

```
frame.addComponentListener( new ComponentListener() {
      public void componentResized( ComponentEvent e ) {}
      public void componentMoved( ComponentEvent e ) {
         setLocation( FIX_X, FIX_Y );
      }
      public void componentShown( ComponentEvent e ) {}
      public void componentHidden( ComponentEvent e ) {}
 } );
```

Comment: Surely you meant `setUndecorated(true)`?

Comment: I've tried to use frame.setUndecorated(true), but now my frame comes up as a grey empty block.

Comment: if you want the frame decorated, choose the CompontentListener solution.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to set location on center of screen:

```
private void centerLocation() throws HeadlessException {
    final Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    final Dimension screenSize = toolkit.getScreenSize();
    final int x = (screenSize.width - this.getWidth()) / 2;
    final int y = (screenSize.height - this.getHeight()) / 2;
    this.setLocation(x, y);
}
```

not movable by the user:

```
setUndecorated(true);
```

EDIT:

```
public static final int TOP_LEFT = 0;
public static final int TOP_RIGHT = 1;
public static final int BOTTOM_LEFT = 2;
public static final int BOTTOM_RIGHT = 3;

public void customLocation(int mode) {
    final Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    final Dimension screenSize = toolkit.getScreenSize();
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    switch (mode) {
        case TOP_LEFT:
            x = 50;
            y = 30;
            break;
        case TOP_RIGHT:
            x = (screenSize.width - this.getWidth()) - 50;
            y = 30;
            break;
        case BOTTOM_LEFT:
            x = 50;
            y = (screenSize.height - this.getHeight()) - 80;
            break;
        case BOTTOM_RIGHT:
            x = (screenSize.width - this.getWidth()) - 50;
            y = (screenSize.height - this.getHeight()) - 80;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    this.setLocation(x, y);
}
```

and also you can move your frame even if your frame is decorated or not:

```
Point initialClick;

addMouseMotionListener(new java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter() {
    public void mouseDragged(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        MouseDragged(evt);
    }
});
addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
    public void mousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        MousePressed(evt);
    }
});

private void MousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    initialClick = evt.getPoint();
}

private void MouseDragged(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    updateLocation(evt);
}

private void updateLocation(MouseEvent evt) {
    int thisX = this.getLocation().x;
    int thisY = this.getLocation().y;
    int xMoved = (thisX + evt.getX()) - (thisX + initialClick.x);
    int yMoved = (thisY + evt.getY()) - (thisY + initialClick.y);
    int x = thisX + xMoved;
    int y = thisY + yMoved;
    this.setLocation(x, y);
}
```

Comment: That seems like a very long way to center a frame. Why doesn't simply `setLocationRelativeTo(null)` after packing work?

Comment: @user3760399 was this helpful?

Comment: I agree that it seems to be slightly long. I didn't try this.